# Argument exception when calling GetList()

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell

I'm trying to get a list, more precisely the Document Library with PowerShell, but I get the following exception and I'm stuck on what I should change:

```
Exception calling "GetList" with "1" argument(s)
+spDocLib = $spWeb.GetList("Dokumenter")
```

This is my script code:

```
function GetDocumentLibrary($completeUrl) {

    $web = Get-SPWeb($completeUrl)

    $DocumentLibrary = $completeUrl + "/Documentlibrary"

    $spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity http://url.com

    $spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()  

    $spDocLib = $spWeb.GetList("Dokumenter")
}
```

Maybe I'm going the wrong way to get to the document library?

Answer (score 2):

Check below solution :

```
$spSite = Get-SpSite "Your URL";
$List = $spSite.RootWeb.Lists["List or library Name"];
```

You can use below method also .

```
public SPList TryGetList(
    string listTitle
)
```

It gives null if list is not exist.

You want to use getList() methos than you have to pass guid of the list.

```
public SPList GetList(
    Guid uniqueId,
    bool fetchMetadata
)
```

Tell me if have any query:
:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try to get `$spSite.RootWeb.Lists["listname"]`, $List is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to pass "Title " of the list as value